# componentDidUpdate continue to be executed after page navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using React-Native, React-Navigation and Redux. I have a sign up page which will send the user information to the server and will listen for a token. Once the token is received, i will change the global state {userLoggedIn: true}.

In my component, i use a componentDidUpdate to check whether userLoggedIn is true, and if it is, then i will redirect to the "Main" page.

```
// component/register
class Register extends Component {
  ...
  componentDidUpdate(){ 
    console.log('componentDidUpdate from the register page')
    if (this.props.people.userLoggedIn==true){
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
    }
  }

  render(){
    //sign up form
  }
}

...
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Register);
```

This works fine as I am redirected to the Main page. However, on the Main page itself, it is refreshing non-stop. I checked the log and saw that componentDidUpdate is still being called from the register page.

Therefore I am a little confuse why is componentDidUpdate still being called? Wouldn't it stop checking after it is being navigated to a new page?

EDIT 1: I realised it is not a problem with componentDidUpdate. I inserted the redirect condition insider the render method, it also causes an infinite loop. I can't understand why it is still trying to render when it is navigated to a new page.

Comment: Even if you navigate to another page, previous page is still on the stack, just hidden not removed. so it will still update when props or state change..

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your SignUp page keeps getting new props and updating after you are navigated to the Main page. I think this is due to `navigation` prop that is updated. In your `componentDidUpdate` you should make sure you are going to change page only in one case - when your `userLoggedIn` is changed from `false` to `true`.

```
// component/register
class Register extends Component {
  ...
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps){ 
    console.log('componentDidUpdate from the register page')
    if (this.props.people.userLoggedIn === true && prevProps.people.userLoggedIn === false) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
    }
  }

  render(){
    //sign up form
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [withNavigationFocus](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation-focus.html) to know if the component is focused.